# Control and Detect Web-cam access by any running process

Tags: c#, windows, api, webcam

I want to detect the access of connected web-cam by any running process and control that access so i can grant the access or deny it.
I am using dot net and have some experience in windows API.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are really trying to do?  If you could hook the webcam access, how would your code decide to "grant access or deny it"?  I have a few ideas, none of which are easy, but would want to know more before I wrote it up.

Comment: I need to prevent undesired access to the web-cam from any running process so when any process want to use the web-cam i will pop-up a message box to tell the user that there is some process need to use your web-cam and ask him for his permission.I hope it is clear now!

Answer (score 0):

1. If you only care about apps that use DirectShow (which is the usual case), you could likely implement a virtual DirectShow source filter that proxies the video frames.  This assumes that the applications you care about can be configured to user your filter and not the native one.
2. Implement a USB filter driver.  Requires programming in C and kernel mode programming.  You need to be very careful if you explore this suggestion.  Otherwise, you could break some other vendors device's driver stack.

In both cases, when you detect the driver being opened, replace all frames that pass through with a stock "black frame" until your user mode app (running on the desktop) has finished prompting the user. (your user mode app would somehow signal the filter that the user is "allowing" the operation.) You'll likely need to support different frame sizes of RGB, MJPG, and YUV/I420.